# how to create a file selector when click button in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, file-browser, getopenfilename

image link

[image]

I want create a gui app with pyqt5.i create one button("Browse") that click on it open a file browser to import data file but it does not work and app closed.please help me i need it.

I've tried on pycharm2018 in windows 10 and i use QTDesigner

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import _pickle
class Ui_Import_data(object):
def browse_data1(self):
    data_path=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Open File',"D:\Programming",'*.txt',)
    with open('data_path.pickle', 'wb') as handle:
        _pickle.dump(data_path,handle,protocol=_pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

def setupUi(self, Import_data):
    Import_data.setObjectName("Import_data")
    Import_data.resize(704, 131)
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Import_data)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 20, 81, 23))
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(Import_data)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 47, 13))
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Import_data)
    self.label_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 20, 121, 16))
    self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
    self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Import_data)
    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 20, 441, 20))
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
    self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(Import_data)
    self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 50, 441, 20))
    self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
    self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Import_data)
    self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 50, 81, 23))
    self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
    self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Import_data)
    self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(600, 100, 81, 23))
    self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
    self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Import_data)
    self.pushButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(510, 100, 75, 23))
    self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
    self.retranslateUi(Import_data)

    self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.browse_data1)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Import_data)

def retranslateUi(self, Import_data):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    Import_data.setWindowTitle(_translate("Import_data", "Import Data"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Import_data", "Browse"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("Import_data", "Data Path"))
    self.label_2.setText(_translate("Import_data", "Ground Truth Data Path"))
    self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Import_data", "Browse"))
    self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Import_data", "Apply"))
    self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Import_data", "OK"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Import_data = QtWidgets.QDialog()
ui = Ui_Import_data()
ui.setupUi(Import_data)
Import_data.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: change `data_path=QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,'Open File',"D:\Programming",'*.txt',)` to `data_path, _ =QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Open File', r"D:\Programming", '*.txt')`

Comment: def fileSelector(self):
        filename, filter = QtGui.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(parent=self.parentWidget(or self), caption='Select image file', filter=' Image files (*.png)')
        if filename:
            print(filename)